# How do I insert records in a Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a record from my form into a database but after click on submit it shows me, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax" error....
please help me

```
<?php
include('data_conn.php');

if(isset($_POST['subm'])){

  $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['email']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) ) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Email is Already Exist...."); location.href="signup.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    else {
        $f_name = $_POST['f_name'];

        $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
        $c_add = $_POST['c_add'];
        $mob = $_POST['mob'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];



        $query = "INSERT INTO login (first_name,company_name,company_add,mob,email,password) VALUES ('$f_name,'$c_name','$c_add','$mob','$email','$password')";


       $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


       if($result==1)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("successfully registered!!!"); location.href="signup.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Something Went Wrong!!! :("); location.href="signup.php"';
    echo '</script>';
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* functions are obsolete and have been removed from PHP 7.  You should use a more modern library such as mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below line

```
$query = "INSERT INTO login (first_name,company_name,company_add,mob,email,password) VALUES ('$f_name,'$c_name','$c_add','$mob','$email','$password')";
```

To this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO login (first_name,company_name,company_add,mob,email,password) VALUES ('$f_name','$c_name','$c_add','$mob','$email','$password')";
```

**The issue is, you added only one `'` to the variable `$f_name`. Just make it like `'$f_name'` and it will work**

Comment: @Rkboss, With pleasure. Please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using direct substitution values, you could use below methods to avoid sql injection.

You basically have two options to achieve this:

1) Using PDO (for any supported database driver):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

2) Using MySQLi (for MySQL):

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Please refer [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax error.**
*Try:*

```
$query = "INSERT INTO login (first_name,company_name,company_add,mob,email,password) VALUES ('$f_name','$c_name','$c_add','$mob','$email','$password')";
```

instead of:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO login (first_name,company_name,company_add,mob,email,password) VALUES ('$f_name,'$c_name','$c_add','$mob','$email','$password')";
```

Missing single quotes in `'$f_name'`.